# comparing dates with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to:  after restart server via first Task , I want to do below steps via script inside Second Task.

1 - Get First Scheduled Task Last run Time

2 - it looks at the day/time it’s running(second task) and Compare First Scheduled Task Last run Time with Today Date

3 - If Scheduled Task Last run Time is equal to current date  (Wednesday, December 6, 2023  ) , Second Task will run.

My task scheduler :

```
first Task : On a Schedule , Recur every 2 weeks on Sunday , Start Time : 12:00 PM  Name: Restart Script Task  restart-computer -force

Second Task : At Startup , working another powershell script
```

My question is :  I will use `if (($LastrunTime) -lt (get-date) )`.  Is there a better way?

For example :

`$LastrunTime` : Wednesday, December 6, 2023 11:44:44 AM

`Get-Date`     : Wednesday, December 6, 2023 11:44:44 PM

I am using `($LastrunTime) -eq (get-date)`. But , it returns `FALSE`.

Not Time , I will compare this `Wednesday, December 6, 2023` part.

Script :

```
 $LastRunTime = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Restart Server" |  Get-ScheduledTaskInfo | select -ExpandProperty LastRunTime
 $LastRunTime

#Wednesday, December 6, 2023 11:44:44 AM


if (($LastrunTime) -lt (get-date) )
{
    
    Write-Host "Second Task is running."
    
}

else {Write-Host "Second Task is not running"}
```

Comment: `Get-Date` returns the current date/time value, and the "last" run is necessarily _in the past_, so your comparison will likely always be true

Comment: So How can we do `equal` between dates?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($LastRunTime -ge $([DateTime]::Today))
    {
    Write-Host "Second Task is running."
    }
else {Write-Host "Second Task is not running"}
```

The "Today" static method will always show the begining of the day which is 12:00AM (midnight)
So if your goal is "as long as it has run "today" then this should work
Otherwise what is the timespan you would like to be within?

Comment: If Scheduled Task Last run Time is equal to current date (Wednesday, December 6, 2023 ) , Second Task will run. So lets say, one day later  I manually rebooted except first task scheduler. As result , LastRunTime ((Wednesday, December 6, 2023 ) will remain the same. But Second task won't run.  So, if 2 dates are equal, the second task will run.